# Calculate the Angle between two vectors in 3d Spherical Coordinates

Tags: geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have two vectors in spherical coordinates, both originating at the origin and both with the same magnitude equal to one.  One is vertical: {1,0,0} and the other undefined: {Ms,Mt,Mp}. The other one can be anywhere depending on an energy equation. I need to know the angle between them. So I take the dot product:

$ (1,0,0) \cdot (Ms,Mt,Mp) = Ms+0+0=Ms= \left| 1\right|  \left| \text{Ms}\right| \cos (\omega )$

Therefore $~~~~\cos (\omega ) = 1 ~~~~~~~~$    and $ ~~~~ \omega = ArcCos[1]$

But, it doesn't make sense that no matter the direction of the vector the angle is constant.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In spherical coordinates, how do you get $(1,0,0) \cdot (Ms,Mt,Mp) = Ms+0+0$? The pairwise multiplication of coordinates is a formula that works in Cartesian coordinates, but the two coordinate systems are very different. Also, if both vectors have magnitude $1$ then $Ms=1$, doesn't it?

Comment: Ms does equal 1.

Comment: I'm looking at dot products and not seeing the adjustment for spherical coordinates.

Comment: There's no "adjustment". It just doesn't work that way at all.

Comment: So my only recourse is to convert to cartesian coordinates, take the dot product, and convert back to spherical coordinates? The integrating Jacobian or the like will not suffice in a vector dot product?

Comment: The $\lVert a\rVert\,\lVert b\rVert\cos\alpha$ formula still works, and in this case the angle is trivially easy to find. The integrating Jacobian is concerned with very small changes in the coordinates, so it don't think it applies directly to two vectors with any significant angle between them. Converting to Cartesian and then multiplying coordinates may be the second-easiest way to do the dot product in this case (and maybe the easiest in the general case of two arbitrary vectors).

Comment: Error is stating that $M_s=1$.

Comment: $\left| \text{Ms}\right|$ is in error!

Comment: Both vectors point to the surface of a sphere, one is on what would be the z-axis in cartesian coordinates, the other is anywhere. 

Did I write the vectors wrong? I wrote Ms in case I want to change the magnitude later, but, for now they are both the same magnitude.